# How to retrieve form data from pre-pre page using PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a form in page1.php and after submitting, it will go to page2.php

which has another form that will take you to page3.php after submitting it.

Now, I can easily get the data from page2.php using

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        
       $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
```

but how can I get from page1's form?
I store one data in a variable in page2.php as you see

```
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        
          $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
```

But when I can't retrieve it from page3.php as it is an Undefined index.

Comment: in page 2 store the variables coming from page1 as hidden inputs and then you can fetch them in page 3.

Comment: Another common way to solve this would be to use [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to store the posted data. Then you can access it where ever. Another solution would be to store the form data in local storage and post it all in the last form (as hidden inputs you populate using js)

Answer (score 0):

You make 2 different HTTP Request, so you can't get the POSTED variables from the page1 in the page3.

You need to pass the variable somewhere in page2.php from page1.php.

You can use COOKIES or SESSIONS maybe.

I would suggest something like that :

On page2.php

```
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    $_SESSION['page1_number1'] = $_POST['number1'];
}
```

On page3.php

You'll have the $_POST['number2'] and the $_SESSION['page1_number1']

```
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
    var_dump($number2);
    var_dump($_SESSION['page1_number1']);
}
```